# sum a column based on two different columns

Tags: python, pandas, sum, pandas-groupby

I am trying to summarize subsec column by controlling year and ticker in the below table. Such that, a new column to be created and sum of df.subsec to be added here.

[the table I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a2kv.png)[image]

[the table I need in the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfu9B.png)[image]

I tried [this data science link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20308/how-to-sum-values-grouped-by-two-columns-in-pandas) by adjusting the code but it didnot work:

```
dfc['k']=dfc.groupby(['ticker', 'year'])['subsec'].sum().sum(level=['ticker', 'year'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify a little the sum and use `reset_index` to adjust the dataframe.

```
df = (
    dfc.groupby(['ticker', 'year'])['subsec']
    .sum()
    .reset_index(name='sumsss')
)
```

Comment: your approach works like a miracle. I have a short question, Do you have any idea about how to drop multiple occurrences?

Comment: For this example? or in general? you might want to look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html `drop_duplicates` method, but for this example maybe my code is not the "right" way to do what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: no here we will have multiple dfc.year variables and actually we dont need them in your suggested approach.  we need one ticker, one year and one sum variable in the end... so the dropping should also be by condition

Comment: In that case, its better to have a different approach than transform. Check the edit.

Comment: yes, thank you so much :) it is resolved. I do really appreciate your help and sparing time.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider following example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c']
df['yr'] = [2008, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2008, 2008]
df['sub'] = [10, 15, 17, 15, 10, 10]
print(df)
   a    yr  sub
0  a  2008   10
1  b  2008   15
2  a  2008   17
3  a  2009   15
4  b  2008   10
5  c  2008   10
```

We can apply groupby and sum() function to above dataframe then finally to_frame() function will give it a column name you want, then you can reset the index..

```
df.groupby(['a', 'yr'])['sub'].sum().to_frame('Total').reset_index()
   a    yr  Total
0  a  2008     27
1  a  2009     15
2  b  2008     25
3  c  2008     10
```